# How to get the width and height of canvas that has auto set?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, height, width

How do I get the height and width of the canvas that has auto set?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) and [ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx).